# Why do some values pass the OR operator, and other do not?

Tags: javascript, debugging, string-comparison

In my code, I'm trying to check whether a sentence is in morse or english based on the characters its using. If its in morse, Decode runs. If english, the Encode function runs. For some reason, certain words such as 'friend' and 'chicken' show up as morse, but words like 'start' and 'zebra' do not. Why does this happen?

```js
var input, output, startType;   
var inputArray = [];            

input = (prompt('Enter the word(s) or sentence(s) that you wish to convert.')).toLowerCase(); 

function checkInput(input) {
    var i, il;
    for (i = 0, il = input.length; i < il; i++) {
        if (input.charAt(i) === ('a'||'b'||'c'||'d'||'e'||'f'||'g'||'h'||'i'||'j'||'k'||'l'||'m'||'n'||'o'||'p'||'q'||'r'||'s'||'t'||'u'||'v'||'w'||'x'||'y'||'z')) {
            startType = 'normal';
            break;
        }
        else {
            startType = 'morse';
            console.log(i);
        }
    }
}
checkInput(input);

function Encode(input) {    
    var i, il;              

    for (i = 0, il = input.length; i < il; i++) {   

        if (input.charAt(i) === 'a') {              
            inputArray.push('.-');                  
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {       
                inputArray.push('/');               
            }                                       
        }                                           

        else if(input.charAt(i) === 'b') {          
            inputArray.push('-...');                
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {       
                inputArray.push('/');               
            }                                       
        }                                           

        else if(input.charAt(i) === 'c') {          
            inputArray.push('-.-.');                
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {       
                inputArray.push('/');               
            }                                       
        }                                           

        else if(input.charAt(i) === 'd') {          
            inputArray.push('-..');                 
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {       
                inputArray.push('/');               
            }                                       
        }                                           

        else if(input.charAt(i) === 'e') {          
            inputArray.push('.');                   
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {       
                inputArray.push('/');               
            }                                       
        }                                           

        else if(input.charAt(i) === 'f') {          
            inputArray.push('..-.');                
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {       
                inputArray.push('/');               
            }                                       
        }                                           

        else if(input.charAt(i) === 'g') {          
            inputArray.push('--.');                 
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {       
                inputArray.push('/');               
            }                                       
        }                                           

        else if(input.charAt(i) === 'h') {          
            inputArray.push('....');                
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {       
                inputArray.push('/');               
            }                                       
        }                                           

        else if(input.charAt(i) === 'i') {          
            inputArray.push('..');                  
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {       
                inputArray.push('/');               
            }                                       
        }                                           

        else if(input.charAt(i) === 'j') {          
            inputArray.push('.---');                
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {       
                inputArray.push('/');               
            }                                       
        }                                           

        else if(input.charAt(i) === 'k') {          
            inputArray.push('-.-');                 
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {       
                inputArray.push('/');               
            }                                       
        }                                           

        else if(input.charAt(i) === 'l') {          
            inputArray.push('.-..');                
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {       
                inputArray.push('/');               
            }                                       
        }                                           

        else if(input.charAt(i) === 'm') {          
            inputArray.push('--');                  
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {       
                inputArray.push('/');               
            }                                       
        }                                           

        else if(input.charAt(i) === 'n') {          
            inputArray.push('-.');                  
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {       
                inputArray.push('/');               
            }                                       
        }                                           

        else if(input.charAt(i) === 'o') {          
            inputArray.push('---');                 
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {       
                inputArray.push('/');               
            }                                       
        }                                           

        else if(input.charAt(i) === 'p') {          
            inputArray.push('.--.');                
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {       
                inputArray.push('/');               
            }                                       
        }                                           

        else if(input.charAt(i) === 'q') {          
            inputArray.push('--.-');                
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {       
                inputArray.push('/');               
            }                                       
        }                                           

        else if(input.charAt(i) === 'r') {          
            inputArray.push('.-.');                 
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {       
                inputArray.push('/');               
            }                                       
        }                                           

        else if(input.charAt(i) === 's') {          
            inputArray.push('...');                 
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {       
                inputArray.push('/');               
            }                                       
        }                                           

        else if(input.charAt(i) === 't') {          
            inputArray.push('-');                   
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {       
                inputArray.push('/');               
            }                                       
        }                                           

        else if(input.charAt(i) === 'u') {          
            inputArray.push('..-');                 
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {       
                inputArray.push('/');               
            }                                       
        }                                           

        else if(input.charAt(i) === 'v') {          
            inputArray.push('...-');                
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {       
                inputArray.push('/');               
            }                                       
        }                                           

        else if(input.charAt(i) === 'w') {          
            inputArray.push('.--');                 
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {       
                inputArray.push('/');               
            }                                       
        }                                           

        else if(input.charAt(i) === 'x') {          
            inputArray.push('-..-');                
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {       
                inputArray.push('/');               
            }                                       
        }                                           

        else if(input.charAt(i) === 'y') {          
            inputArray.push('-.--');                
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {       
                inputArray.push('/');               
            }                                       
        }                                           

        else if(input.charAt(i) === 'z') {          
            inputArray.push('--..');                
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {       
                inputArray.push('/');               
            }                                       
        }                                           

        else if(input.charAt(i) === '0') {          
            inputArray.push('-----');               
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {       
                inputArray.push('/');               
            }                                       
        }                                           

        else if(input.charAt(i) === '1') {          
            inputArray.push('.----');               
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {       
                inputArray.push('/');               
            }                                       
        }                                           

        else if(input.charAt(i) === '2') {          
            inputArray.push('..---');               
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {       
                inputArray.push('/');               
            }                                       
        }                                           

        else if(input.charAt(i) === '3') {          
            inputArray.push('...--');               
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {       
                inputArray.push('/');               
            }                                       
        }                                           

        else if(input.charAt(i) === '4') {          
            inputArray.push('....-');               
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {       
                inputArray.push('/');               
            }                                       
        }                                           

        else if(input.charAt(i) === '5') {          
            inputArray.push('.....');               
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {       
                inputArray.push('/');               
            }                                       
        }                                           

        else if(input.charAt(i) === '6') {          
            inputArray.push('-....');               
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {       
                inputArray.push('/');               
            }                                       
        }                                           

        else if(input.charAt(i) === '7') {          
            inputArray.push('--...');               
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {       
                inputArray.push('/');               
            }                                       
        }                                           

        else if(input.charAt(i) === '8') {          
            inputArray.push('---..');               
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {       
                inputArray.push('/');               
            }                                       
        }                                           

        else if(input.charAt(i) === '9') {          
            inputArray.push('----.');               
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {       
                inputArray.push('/');               
            }                                       
        }                                           

        else if(input.charAt(i) === '.') {          
            inputArray.push('.-.-.-');              
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {       
                inputArray.push('/');               
            }                                       
        }                                           

        else if(input.charAt(i) === '?') {          
            inputArray.push('..--..');              
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {       
                inputArray.push('/');               
            }                                       
        }                                           

        else if(input.charAt(i) === '!') {          
            inputArray.push('-.-.--');              
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {       
                inputArray.push('/');               
            }                                       
        }                                           

        else if(input.charAt(i) === ('(')) {        
            inputArray.push('-.--.');               
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {       
                inputArray.push('/');               
            }                                       
        }                                           

        else if(input.charAt(i) === (')')) {        
            inputArray.push('-.--.-');              
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {       
                inputArray.push('/');               
            }                                       
        }                                           

        else if(input.charAt(i) === ':') {          
            inputArray.push('---...');              
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {       
                inputArray.push('/');               
            }                                       
        }                                           

        else if(input.charAt(i) === '=') {          
            inputArray.push('-...-');               
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {       
                inputArray.push('/');               
            }                                       
        }                                           

        else if(input.charAt(i) === '-') {          
            inputArray.push('-....-');              
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {       
                inputArray.push('/');               
            }                                       
        }                                           

        else if(input.charAt(i) === '"') {          
            inputArray.push('.-..-.');              
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {       
                inputArray.push('/');               
            }                                       
        }                                           

        else if(input.charAt(i) === ',') {          
            inputArray.push('--..--');              
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {       
                inputArray.push('/');               
            }                                       
        }                                           

        else if(input.charAt(i) === "'") {          
            inputArray.push('.----.');              
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {       
                inputArray.push('/');               
            }                                       
        }                                           

        else if(input.charAt(i) === '/') {          
            inputArray.push('-..-.');              
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {       
                inputArray.push('/');               
            }                                       
        }                                           

        else if(input.charAt(i) === '&') {          
            inputArray.push('.-...');               
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {       
                inputArray.push('/');               
            }                                       
        }                                           

        else if(input.charAt(i) === ';') {          
            inputArray.push('-.-.-');               
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {       
                inputArray.push('/');               
            }                                       
        }                                           

        else if(input.charAt(i) === '_') {          
            inputArray.push('..--.-');              
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {       
                inputArray.push('/');               
            }                                       
        }                                           

        else if(input.charAt(i) === '@') {          
            inputArray.push('.--.-.');              
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {       
                inputArray.push('/');               
            }                                       
        }                                           

        else if(input.charAt(i) === ' ') {          
            inputArray.push('//');                  
        }                                           

        else {                                      
            inputArray.push(input.charAt(i));       
        }                                           

    }   
}       

switch(startType) {
    case 'normal':
        Encode(input);
        output = inputArray.join('');   
        break;
    case 'morse':
        Decode(input);
        output = inputArray.join('');   
        break;
    default:
        output = 'Unrecognized language!';
        break;
}

console.log('Input was: ' + input);     
console.log('Output is: ' + output);    
console.log('Start type was: ' + startType);
```

```html
<script src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

<s>Have you tried removing the parentheses surrounding your character choices?</s>

```
  if (input.charAt(i) === 'a'||'b'||'c'||'d'||'e'||'f'||'g'||'h'||'i'||'j'||'k'||'l'||'m'||'n'||'o'||'p'||'q'||'r'||'s'||'t'||'u'||'v'||'w'||'x'||'y'||'z')
```

Use this instead:

```
if (['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'].indexOf(input.charAt(i)) > -1)
```

Sorry for misleading you there!

Comment: No, that condition will always be truthy. The === operator tests against one value, not against a list of values.

Answer (score 2):

Because `('a'||'b'||'c'||'d'||'e'||'f'||'g'||'h'||'i'||'j'||'k'||'l'||'m'||'n'||'o'||'p'||'q'||'r'||'s'||'t'||'u'||'v'||'w'||'x'||'y'||'z')` will always return `a` so if your string has an `a` in it then it will be considered as a `normal` type.

If you just want to check whether the `input` has only alphabet[`a-z`] characters then you can use

```
function checkInput(input) {
  startType = /^[a-z]+$/.test(input) ? 'normal' : 'morse';
  console.log(startType)
}
```